# React Update state in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the state in the parent component when a file is successfully uploaded. The file upload successfully and the promise executes as expected.

The issue is that I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined

on line:

> promise.then(this.props.action())

How do I resolve this error and update the state in the parent component?

```
class FileUploadWidget extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        var self=this;
        let fileName = this.props.file
        let payrollID = this.props.payrollID
        const inputElement = document.getElementById(this.props.file);
        if(inputElement){
        inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, true);
        }


  function handleFiles() {

        const self = this;
        const fileList = this.files; 
        const uri = "******/fileupload.php";
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const fd = new FormData();

        const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { 
            resolve("Success")
            }
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 400) {
              alert(xhr.responseText); 
            }
        };

        fd.append('myFile', fileList[0]);
        fd.append('fileID', fileName)
        fd.append('payrollID', payrollID)
        fd.append('origionalFileName', fileList[0]["name"]);
        xhr.send(fd);
    })

    promise.then(this.props.action())
      }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="file" id={this.props.file}></input> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Parent Component:

```
class UploadRequired extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {status: ""};
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
      }

      handler() {
          console.log("State set!!")
        this.setState({
           state: "0"
        });
    }
       componentWillReceiveProps = props => {
        this.setState({ status : props.dataRow });
}

    render() {

        var button = <div></div>;

        if(this.state.status == ""){
                button = <FileUploadWidget file={this.props.file} payrollID={this.props.payrollID} action={() => this.handler()}/>;
              }

              if(this.state.status == "0"){
                button = <ProcessWidget />;
              }
              if(this.state.status == "1"){
                button = <ProcessingWidget />;
              }
              if(this.state.status == "2"){
                button = <ProcessedWidget />;
              }
        return(
            <div>
            {button}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default UploadRequired;
```

Comment: this.handleFiles= this.handleFiles.bind(this);  you need to bind your function in component constructor

Comment: Hi when I bind the function I get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: Could you provide the code example of the parent component?

Comment: @RomanUnt I have edited to include parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to bind `this` to your method.

Try using an arrow function:

```
inputElement.addEventListener("change", () => handleFiles(), true)
```

Or the classic binding in the constructor, and make it a class function:

```
constructor () {    
    this.handleFiles= this.handleFiles.bind(this)
}

function componentDidMount () { ... }

function handleFiles () { ... }
```

**Edit:**
Even a 3rd option of passing `this` as a context comes to mind, although it doesn't look very good IMO:

```
inputElement.addEventListener('change', () => handleFiles(this), true)

function handleFiles (context) {
    // ...

    promise.then(context.props.action())
}
```

Comment: Hi, When I implement the 3rd solution the constant "FilesList" is now undefined where I append it to the form data. I have changed the declaration to "const fileList = context.files; "

Comment: Where do `files` come from? Where is it declared?

Comment: I think you're declaring `files` in the global scope but `handleFiles` has the component's scope. So either use one or the other. Maybe pass `files` as another property to `FileUploadWidget`.